# Online games: update the clients with deltas or with the new status

Tags: java, android, online-game

I'm implementing a online chess for Android and I have a question about how to update the players with the other player's movements.

For example lets imagine the Player1 moves his tower from a1 to a7.

What should I do?

- Send to the Player2: **"a1 to a7"** (with some kind of checksum of the full board to avoid errors)
- Send to the Player2 the full board with the up to 32 pieces

Comment: I'd use lockstep and just send 'a1 to a7'. Lockstep will ensure both parties run the same simulation. Shouldn't be hard to implement since it's only 2 player.

Comment: It's always better to send deltas than to send full game state whenever possible. Think about a game like Minecraft, with thousands of tiles. If you had to tell every client in a multiplayer game 'This tile? Hasn't changed. This tile? Hasn't changed. *10000' you would run out of bandwidth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Support both.

- Only send deltas during events, but
- Allow the client to request full state, for any reason, through a separate API.
- Include and increment a sequence number with each event so that it is trivial for a client to detect missed updates.